# getTokenSilentlyEquivalent that avoids third party cookies

Tags: oauth-2.0, auth0

I wrote a [cypress plugin](https://github.com/thefrontside/simulacrum/tree/v0/integrations/cypress) that helps to simulate `auth0` for testing without having to go through the whole redirect to and from the login pages.

It uses silent authentication or `getTokenSilently` to avoid the redirects etc.

```
  return new Cypress.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let person = atom.slice(Cypress.spec.name, 'person').get();

    assert(!!person && typeof person.email !== 'undefined', `no scenario in login`);

    auth0Client.getTokenSilently({ ignoreCache: true, currentUser: person.email, test: Cypress.currentTest.title })
    .then((token) => {
      log(`successfully logged in with token ${JSON.stringify(token)}`);

      resolve(token);
    }).catch((e) => {
      console.error(e);

      reject(e);
    });
  })
```

The auth0 docs appear to be saying that [silent authentication](https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/refresh-tokens/refresh-token-rotation) is not the preferred way for single-page applications.

This post [Refresh token rotation](https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/refresh-tokens/refresh-token-rotation) does not suggest an alternative to `getTokenSilently` that does not use third-party cookies.

If I look at the source code in `@auth0/spa-js`, `getTokenSilently` still appears to use cookies, even if you have

```
scope: "offline_access",
useRefreshTokens: true
```

I am confused as to what is an alternative to `getTokenSilently` that does not use third party cookies.

getTokenSilently also does not currently work in safari because of this reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SECURED SPA TESTS**

The simplest all round option might be to do a full redirect at the start of your test suite, as in [this Curity code example](https://github.com/curityio/spa-using-token-handler/tree/main/spa), which uses Cypress tests. This has the advantage that the SPA can call real APIs afterwards. It will also work in all browsers including Safari. It is probably the option I would use.

**GETTING MOCK TOKENS IN CLIENTS**

I like your mock plugin idea, since at times it is useful to be able to bypass some of the Authorization Server behaviour, if it gets in the way of testing.

It feels like infrastructure that you cannot control is getting in your way though. Perhaps your plugin should not need to depend on client side SDKs. Maybe you could just have a mock `getTokenSilently` that issues its own tokens using a JWT library?

- [Token issuing code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.nodejs/blob/master/test/utils/tokenIssuer.ts)

It depends though on what you want to do next, eg do you want to call real APIs? If so then the Secured SPA Tests option might be simplest.

**USING MOCK TOKENS IN APIs**

One useful technique to be aware of is the [Wiremock](https://wiremock.org/) tool, which can register canned responses with tokens base on tokens you've issued in your own test code. Here are some [API tests of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.nodejs/blob/master/test/integrationTests.ts) that use this approach.

In my case the API requires user level tokens and a code flow by default. These tests enable a more productive API development setup, where the API code validates mock tokens in the standard way. It may not be such a good fit for SPA tests though.

**SILENT REDIRECTS**

In a real SPA, `getTokenSilently` relies on the Authorization Server's (third party) SSO cookie. A code flow is run on a hidden iframe to get new tokens, using OpenID Connect's `prompt=none` request parameter. This does not work in the Safari browser with default settings, since it drops the SSO cookie, as part of an initiative to prevent third parties from tracking users.

**BACKEND FOR FRONTEND**

To solve the above problem in a real SPA, the current best practice is to use first party cookies instead of relying on the SSO session cookie. An SPA running at `https://example.com` can use an API at `https://api.example.com` to enable this. More on this theme in the [Token Handler Pattern](https://curity.io/resources/learn/token-handler-overview/).

Comment: I actually only use getTokenSilently in this cypress plugin I wrote , I don't do it in production apps https://github.com/thefrontside/simulacrum/blob/v0/integrations/cypress/cypress/support/commands/auth0_react/login.ts#L14 .  I'd just like an equivalent that does not use 3rd party cookies

Comment: Interesting - I added a few notes on mocking and testing. The main thing is to think it through end-to-end I think, so that you are in control of the test ingredients you are using and do not get blocked.

Comment: thank you for the answers.  Very useful.  In a lot of the places I work, the continuous integration environments that run the tests do not have access or have very limited access to the internet so redirecting to auth0 server is a bad thing.

There is also the problem of seeding the data, creating fake accounts and maintaining them via tenant is cumbersome and does not scale well.  Having a full server you can control has proven a real winner

Comment: I like the token issuing idea